# How can I assert a function has `await`ed an async function using should.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon, should.js

I have an async function `f` that calls another async function `g`. To test if `f` calls `g`, I'm stubbing `g` using sinon and assert it's been called using should.js.

```
'use strict';

require('should-sinon');
const sinon = require('sinon');

class X {
    async f(n) {
        await this.g(n);
        // this.g(n); // I forget to insert `await`!
    }
    async g(n) {
        // Do something asynchronously
    }
}

describe('f', () => {
    it('should call g', async () => {
        const x = new X();
        sinon.stub(x, 'g').resolves();
        await x.f(10);
        x.g.should.be.calledWith(10);
    });
});
```

But this test passes even when I forget to use `await` when calling `g` in `f`.

One of the ways to catch this error is to make the stub return a dummy promise and check if its `then` is called.

```
it('should call g', async () => {
    const x = new X();
    const dummyPromise = {
        then: sinon.stub().yields()
    };
    sinon.stub(x, 'g').returns(dummyPromise);
    await x.f(10);
    x.g.should.be.calledWith(10);
    dummyPromise.then.should.be.called();
});
```

But this is a bit bothersome. Are there any convenient ways to do this?

Comment: Does `should-sinon` pull in `sinon`? Presumably you'd want to `require('sinon')` *before* `require('should-sinon')`?

Answer (score 0):

Your example for `f` shows flawed code design which becomes more obvious if you write the same function without `async/await` syntax:

`f(n) {
  return g(n).then(()=>{});
}`

This achieves the same behavior - whether `g` resolved becomes hard to tell (assuming you don't know if `f` returned `g`'s promise, which is the same as not knowing whether `f` awaited `g`). If `f` is not interested in the result of `g` it should just simply return it, not hide it. Then you can simply test for the result.

If your point is that `f` might have to trigger several `async` calls sequentially `await`ing several `g_1`, `g_2`,... to resolve, then you can build a test chain by asserting in the stub of `g_n+1` that the dummy-promise of `g_n` has been resolved. In general your approach to test a dummy-promise for its status is fine.

Comment: I don't necessarily agree that this is flawed code design. It could be that he doesn't want the promise returned by `f` to expose the value with which `g` resolves. Your example with `then` syntax is exactly how one might do this without `async/await`.

Comment: I see your point, and yes there might be cases when you don't want to return what `g` returns. You might want to call several `g_1`, `g_2`,... as I mentioned, or just one but might want to prevent access to a reference - however even in those cases I still think it's cleaner to return some specific mapping, an instance ID for example. Completly hiding the result of a proxied function while wanting testable guarantees that the proxied function ran seems a bit paradoxical.

Comment: That's reasonable. Really it all comes down to what `g` actually does, and what of that operation is acceptable to expose through `f`. Certainly the test would be cleaner without having to track the completion status of `g` manually, as I do in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stubbing `then`, you're best off stubbing `g` in such a way that it sets some boolean on the next event loop iteration. Then, you can check this boolean after calling `f` to make sure `f` waited for it:

```
it('should call g', async () => {
    const x = new X();
    let gFinished = false;
    sinon.stub(x, 'g').callsFake(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            setImmediate(() => {
                gFinished = true;
                resolve();
            });
        });
    });
    await x.f(10);
    x.g.should.be.calledWith(10);
    gFinished.should.be.true();
});
```

Edit: Of course, this isn't a *perfect* guarantee because you could have `f` wait on any promise that waits at least as long as it takes for `g` to resolve. Like so:

```
async f(n) {
    this.g(n);
    await new Promise((resolve) => {
        setImmediate(() => {
            resolve();
        });
    });
}
```

This would cause the test I wrote to pass, even though it's still incorrect. So really it comes down to how strict you're trying to be with your tests. Do you want it to be *literally impossible* to have a false positive? Or is it ok if some obvious trickery can potentially throw it off?

In most cases I find that the latter is ok, but really that's up to you and/or your team.